# How to run dmalloc in linux(OPENSUSE)?

Tags: linux

file : main.c

to run dmalloc I have done the following step.

1)   gcc -ldmalloc -o test main.c

2)  function dmalloc { eval `command dmalloc -b $*`; }

```
dmalloc -l logfile -i 100 low
```

3)  ./test

where  will I get the result?

Even i could not get the logfile.

Comment: Provided `dmalloc -l logfile -i 100 low` went fine, logfile should be in your current dir. Else try using absolute path. Also commit some mistakes like double free etc to make sure the logfile is generated

Comment: @Pavan Manjunath; I did it but  did not get the result

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your environment actually contains the DMALLOC_OPTIONS variable before running the program. Different shells may be different with the eval. Make sure you actually do a malloc in your test program, else it may not have initialized properly.